# What does the scheme $H\cap X$ mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I’m reading Hartshorne.

> Theorem 8.18 (Bertini’s Theorem). Let $X$ be a nonsingular closed subvariety of $\Bbb P_k^n$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Then there exists a hyperplane $H\subset \Bbb P_k^n$, not containing $X$, and such that the scheme $H\cap X$ is regular at every point…

What does the scheme $H\cap X$ mean?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a great question that every student of algebraic geometry needs to ask at some point.

The direct scheme-theoretic interpretation is that $H \cap X$ refers to the fibered product $H \times_{\mathbb{P}^n_k} X$.

Alternatively, closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ are in bijection with homogeneous ideals of $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$. If $I_H$ is the homogeneous ideal corresponding to $H$, and $I_X$ is the homogeneous ideal corresponding to $X$, then $I_H + I_X$ is the homogeneous ideal corresponding to $H \cap X$, and so $H \cap X \cong \operatorname{Proj} k[x_0, \dots, x_n]/(I_H + I_X)$ as a scheme.

Comment: I would argue against giving $H\cap X$ the reduced induced structure, *especially* in the case of Bertini's theorem - the singularities you're looking to avoid can easily be non-reduced in nature.

Comment: In particular, if you reduce then in the case where $H \cap X$ is $0$-dimensional the theorem says nothing at all.

Comment: @kreiser thanks, good point! Edited.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing - closed subchemes are in bijection with saturated homogeneous ideals, not just homogeneous ideals. For instance, $(x)$ and $(x^2,xy)$ give the same subscheme of the projective line.